# Both radio buttons are allowed to be checked at the same time in GTK

Tags: c, radio-button, gtk

I am trying to develop a GUI that has radio buttons. The radio buttons are created after a method read the names of the buttons from a text file and then those are the names of the buttons.

The buttons are created and are showing properly. My problem is that both of them are selected at the same time. How do you get it only allow one to be  checked at the same time?

```
static void sel_sets_prac()
{
    GtkWidget *window,*button,*vbox,*label,*frame;
    window=gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    g_signal_connect(window,"delete-event",G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit),NULL);
    gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window), "ZHONG FC - Sets de Práctica");

    vbox = gtk_vbox_new(FALSE,3);

    frame = gtk_frame_new("Sets de Práctica");
    label = gtk_label_new("Escoge el set que desea practicar: ");
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(frame), label);
    gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(vbox),frame,TRUE,TRUE,0);

    //These variables are from other methods; I am pretty sure the problem is not here
    int num_sets = get_number_sets();
    char ** set_names;
    set_names = get_set_names(num_sets);

    GtkWidget *sets_select[num_sets];

    //I am guessing the problem is here, but I don't have a clue what to do
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < num_sets; i++) {
        sets_select[i] = gtk_radio_button_new_with_label(NULL, set_names[i]);
        gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(vbox),sets_select[i],TRUE,TRUE,0);
    }

    gtk_container_set_border_width(GTK_CONTAINER(window), 50);
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window),vbox);

    gtk_widget_show_all(window);
    gtk_main();
}
```

I can't figure out why multiple buttons are allowed to be selected at the same time. Please help.

Comment: Did you try looking in the [documentation](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.7/GtkRadioButton.html#GtkRadioButton.description)? The RadioButton description spends several paragraphs explaining this.

Answer (score 0):

Your buttons are in different lists, so GTK doesn't know to only allow one of them at a time.  Your problem is the NULL first argument to `gtk_radio_button_new_with_label`; it needs to specify a button list so that all of your radio buttons are treated as a group.  You need something like this (adapted from [this tutorial](http://www.mathematik.uni-ulm.de/help/gtk+-1.1.3/gtk_tut-6.html)):

```
GtkWidget * button = gtk_radio_button_new_with_label (NULL, "button1");
GSList * group = gtk_radio_button_group (GTK_RADIO_BUTTON (button));
GtkWidget * button2 = gtk_radio_button_new_with_label(group, "button2");
```